# How to use non-static variables in this code?

Tags: java

So, I'm doing my coursework at the moment and I stack in the end of a process. When I do my variables static program works, but gives result only in as several lines of the same planet, plus when managed to make the code work without static elements it was giving result of nullpointerexception.

So here I am asking someone at the internet to help explain where's my mistake in the code and how to fix it.

This is my code:

```
        import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SolarSystem {

private double luminosity;
private String solarName;
private ArrayList<Planet> planetList = new ArrayList<>();
public SolarSystem(String solarName, double luminosity) {
    this.solarName = solarName;
    this.luminosity = luminosity;
}

public double getLuminosity() {
    return luminosity;
}

public String getsolarName() {
    return solarName;
}

public void addPlanet(String name, double mass, double distance) {
    Planet newPlanet = new Planet();
    planetList.add(newPlanet);
}

public String toString() {
    String myString = solarName + "\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < planetList.size(); i++){      
        String name = Planet.getPlanetname();
          /*So, in this part I need somehow to call components of another class to make this thing work
*but I have no idea how to do it, as if I'll try to make it static to call them directly
*they won't change what I want to do as I have about  7 abjects which I need to output as a text
*similar to test program
*/

        double mass =Planet.getmass(i);
        double distance = ((SolarSystem.Planet) this.Planet).getdist(i);
        double period = ((SolarSystem.Planet) this.Planet).getPeriod();
        String habitable = ((SolarSystem.Planet) this.Planet).getHabitable(i);
            myString = myString + " Planet " + name + " has a mass of " + mass + " Earths, is " + distance + "AU from its star, and orbits in " + period + " years: could be habitable? "+ habitable+ "\n";
    }


    return myString;
}



}





class Planet {
    SolarSystem system;
    private String name;
    private double mass;
    private double distance;
    private double period;
    private String habitable;
    private double luminosity;
    private double sqlum;
    public Planet() {
        this.name=name;
        this.mass = mass;
        this.distance = distance;
        distance=Math.round(distance*1000)/1000;
        this.luminosity=luminosity;
        period = java.lang.Math.sqrt(distance * distance * distance);
       period= Math.round(period*1000.0)/1000.0;
       period=this.period;
        sqlum = java.lang.Math.sqrt(luminosity);
        if ((mass >= 0.6) && (mass <= 7.0) && (distance >= 0.75 * sqlum) && (distance <= 2.0 * sqlum)) {
            habitable = "yes";

        } else {
            habitable = "no";
        }
    }

    public static String getPlanetname() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public double getPeriod(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return period;
    }

    public double getdist(int i) {
        return distance;
    }

    public double getmass(int i) {
        return mass;
    }

    public String getPlanetname(int i) {
        return name;
    }
    public double getPeriod() {
        return period;
    }


    public String getHabitable(int i) {
        return habitable;
    }

    public double setPeriod(int i) {
        this.period=period;
        return period;
    }
    public String setHabitable(int i) {

        return habitable;
    }
    public double setdist(int i) {
        return distance;
    }
    public double mass(int i) {
        return mass;
    }
}
```

I know that my main problem is toString method, but I just don't see what to change in it to not brake it even more.

This is the test program and the result which I'm trying to reach:

```
       //Uncomment if using extra tests
       //import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

       /*This is the automatic test class for CS-110 coursework 2. The output of the student's program
       * under test should match the string TARGET_OUTPUT_SUN
       */
         public class AutoTest {

static final String TARGET_OUTPUT_SUN = "Our System\n"
        + "Planet Mercury has a mass of 0.055 Earths, is 0.387AU from its star, and orbits in 0.241 years: could be habitable? no\n"
        + "Planet Venus has a mass of 0.815 Earths, is 0.723AU from its star, and orbits in 0.615 years: could be habitable? no\n"
        + "Planet Earth has a mass of 1.0 Earths, is 1.0AU from its star, and orbits in 1.0 years: could be habitable? yes\n"
        + "Planet Mars has a mass of 0.107 Earths, is 1.52AU from its star, and orbits in 1.874 years: could be habitable? no\n"
        + "Planet Jupiter has a mass of 317.8 Earths, is 5.2AU from its star, and orbits in 11.858 years: could be habitable? no\n"
        + "Planet Saturn has a mass of 95.2 Earths, is 9.58AU from its star, and orbits in 29.652 years: could be habitable? no\n"
        + "Planet Uranus has a mass of 14.5 Earths, is 19.2AU from its star, and orbits in 84.13 years: could be habitable? no\n"
        + "Planet Neptune has a mass of 17.1 Earths, is 30.05AU from its star, and orbits in 164.728 years: could be habitable? no\n";

static final String TARGET_OUTPUT_TRAPPIST1 = "Trappist 1\n" +
        "Planet Trappist1b has a mass of 1.017 Earths, is 0.012AU from its star, and orbits in 0.001 years: could be habitable? no\n" +
        "Planet Trappist1c has a mass of 1.156 Earths, is 0.016AU from its star, and orbits in 0.002 years: could be habitable? no\n" +
        "Planet Trappist1d has a mass of 0.297 Earths, is 0.022AU from its star, and orbits in 0.003 years: could be habitable? no\n" +
        "Planet Trappist1e has a mass of 0.772 Earths, is 0.029AU from its star, and orbits in 0.005 years: could be habitable? yes\n" +
        "Planet Trappist1f has a mass of 0.934 Earths, is 0.038AU from its star, and orbits in 0.007 years: could be habitable? yes\n" +
        "Planet Trappist1g has a mass of 1.148 Earths, is 0.049AU from its star, and orbits in 0.011 years: could be habitable? yes\n" +
        "Planet Trappist1h has a mass of 0.331 Earths, is 0.062AU from its star, and orbits in 0.015 years: could be habitable? no\n";

public static void main(String[] args) {


    //Create our solar system
    SolarSystem ourSystem = new SolarSystem("Our System",1.0);

    //Add planets in our solar system
    ourSystem.addPlanet("Mercury", 0.055, 0.387);
    ourSystem.addPlanet("Venus", 0.815, 0.723);
    ourSystem.addPlanet("Earth", 1.0, 1.0);
    ourSystem.addPlanet("Mars", 0.107, 1.52);
    ourSystem.addPlanet("Jupiter", 317.8, 5.20);
    ourSystem.addPlanet("Saturn", 95.2, 9.58);
    ourSystem.addPlanet("Uranus", 14.5, 19.20);
    ourSystem.addPlanet("Neptune", 17.1, 30.05);

    //Check the output for our solar system
    if (ourSystem.toString().equals(TARGET_OUTPUT_SUN)) {
        System.out.println("Solar System: Pass!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Solar System: Fail!\n*****");
        System.out.println("Expected output:\n");
        System.out.println(TARGET_OUTPUT_SUN);
        System.out.println("\n\nActual output:\n");
        System.out.println(ourSystem.toString());
        // Uncomment if using extra tests*/
        /*System.out.println("\n\nDifferences:");
        System.out.println(StringUtils.difference(ourSystem.toString(),
        TARGET_OUTPUT_SUN));*/
    }

    System.out.println("\n\n");//blank lines to separate output

    //Create the Trappist1 system - a much dimmer star with closer planets
    SolarSystem trappist1 = new SolarSystem("Trappist 1",0.00128);

    //Add planets in Trappist 1 system
    trappist1.addPlanet("Trappist1b", 1.017, 0.012);
    trappist1.addPlanet("Trappist1c", 1.156, 0.016);
    trappist1.addPlanet("Trappist1d", 0.297, 0.022);
    trappist1.addPlanet("Trappist1e", 0.772, 0.029);
    trappist1.addPlanet("Trappist1f", 0.934, 0.038);
    trappist1.addPlanet("Trappist1g", 1.148, 0.049);
    trappist1.addPlanet("Trappist1h", 0.331, 0.062);

    //Check the output for trappist1
    if (trappist1.toString().equals(TARGET_OUTPUT_TRAPPIST1)) {
        System.out.println("Trappist1: Pass!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Trappist1: Fail!\n*****");
        System.out.println("Expected output:\n");
        System.out.println(TARGET_OUTPUT_TRAPPIST1);
        System.out.println("\n\nActual output:\n");
        System.out.println(trappist1.toString());
        // Uncomment if using extra tests*/
        /*System.out.println("\n\nDifferences:");
        System.out.println(StringUtils.difference(ourSystem.toString(),
        TARGET_OUTPUT_TRAPPIST1));*/
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Change `String name = Planet.getPlanetname();` to `String name = planetList.get(i).getPlanetname();` with `for(int i = 0; i < planetList.size(); i++){` you are iterating `i` from `0` to the size of your `List`; why did you think you did not need to use `i` ***or*** the `List`?

Comment: In rounding distance you should use 1000.0 instead of 1000. And your habitable-formula makes Earth not habitable.

Comment: OK. I forgot luminosity. And in the tostring-Method was a blank to much.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the problem has to do with the initialization of your planets. You are never setting the values for your planets.

You have to use a constructor like this:

```
public void addPlanet(String name, double mass, double distance) {
    Planet newPlanet = new Planet(name, mass, distance);
    planetList.add(newPlanet);
}
```

And in you planet class your constructor must look similar to this:

```
public Planet(String name, double mass, double distance) {
    this.name = name;
    this.mass = mass;
    this.distance = distance;
}
```

Without passing the arguments to the constructor these values are never set and will always be null.

Answer (score 0):

Well firstly there is this:

```
public void addPlanet(String name, double mass, double distance) {
    Planet newPlanet = new Planet();
    planetList.add(newPlanet);
}
```

This method doesnt work like this. What currently happens is the following: You call the method Solarsystem.addPlanet(..) with planet data, next you create a new planet (which is empty!) and add it to the list. 
You added a planet with all null fields to the list, regardless of what data you submited as params.

To make this work, either build the planet first or assign the variables. We come back to this later.
next up is your planet constructor.
While the thought is okay (building a new planet while instantiating it) the code doesnt work. Again, all the fields (mass, name etc.) are empty. To make these 2 methods work you need to assign the variables.

```
public Planet() {
        this.name=name;
        this.mass = mass;
        this.distance = distance;
        distance=Math.round(distance*1000)/1000;
        this.luminosity=luminosity;
        period = java.lang.Math.sqrt(distance * distance * distance);
       period= Math.round(period*1000.0)/1000.0;
       period=this.period;
        sqlum = java.lang.Math.sqrt(luminosity);
        if ((mass >= 0.6) && (mass <= 7.0) && (distance >= 0.75 * sqlum) && (distance <= 2.0 * sqlum)) {
            habitable = "yes";

        } else {
            habitable = "no";
        }
    }
```

Try the following:

```
public void addPlanet(String name, double mass, double distance) {
    Planet newPlanet = new Planet(name, mass, distance);
    planetList.add(newPlanet);
}
```

(notice that the data gets passed into the planet?)

```
public Planet(String name, double mass, double distance) {
        this.name=name;
        this.mass = mass;
        this.distance=Math.round(distance*1000)/1000;
        this.luminosity=luminosity;//<this is still empty now and could cause a nullpointer
        this.period = java.lang.Math.sqrt(distance * distance * distance);
       this.period= Math.round(period*1000.0)/1000.0;//this overrides the above value
        sqlum = java.lang.Math.sqrt(luminosity);
        if ((mass >= 0.6) && (mass <= 7.0) && (distance >= 0.75 * sqlum) && (distance <= 2.0 * sqlum)) {
            habitable = "yes";

        } else {
            habitable = "no";
        }
    }
```

The best however, would be to do the following;

```
class Planet {
    private String name;
    private double mass;
    private double distance;
    private double period;
    private bool habitable;
    private double luminosity;
    private double sqlum;

    public Planet() {
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name=name;}
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;}
    public void setMass(double mass){
        this.mass=mass;}
    public double getMass(){
        return this.mass;}
    public void setDistance(double distance){
        this.distance=Math.round(distance*1000)/1000;}
    public double getDistance(){
        return this.distance;}
    public void setPeriod(double period){
        this.period=period;}
    public double getPeriod(){
        return this.period;}
    public double calculatePeriod(){
        if(this.distance!=0.0){
            double tmpPeriod = java.lang.Math.sqrt(this.distance * this.distance * this.distance);
            this.period= Math.round(tmpPeriod*1000.0)/1000.0;
        }
        return this.period;}
    public void setLuminosity(double luminosity){
        this.sqlum = java.lang.Math.sqrt(luminosity);}
    public double getLuminosity(){
        return this.sqlum;}
    public bool isPlanetHabitable(){
         if ((this.mass >= 0.6) && (this.mass <= 7.0) && (this.distance >= 0.75 * this.sqlum) && (this.distance <= 2.0 * this.sqlum)) {
            this.habitable = true;

        } else {
            this.habitable = false;
        }
    return habitable;}


}
```

Then you can do the next in your addPlanet method:

```
public void addPlanet(String name, double mass, double distance, double luminosity) {
    Planet newPlanet = new Planet();
newPlanet.setName(name);
newPlanet.setMass(mass);
newPlanet.setDistance(distance);
newPlanet.calculatePeriod();
newPlanet.setLuminosity(luminosity);
    planetList.add(newPlanet);
}
```

Now a planet with all fields filled will be added to your list.

Answer (score 0):

After several changes I got your test passed.

```
public class SolarSystem {

private final double luminosity;
private final String solarName;
private final ArrayList<Planet> planetList = new ArrayList<>();

public SolarSystem(String solarName, double luminosity) {
    this.solarName = solarName;
    this.luminosity = luminosity;
}

public double getLuminosity() {
    return luminosity;
}

public String getSolarName() {
    return solarName;
}

public void addPlanet(String name, double mass, double distance) {
    Planet newPlanet = new Planet(name, mass, distance, luminosity);
    planetList.add(newPlanet);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String myString = solarName + "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < planetList.size(); i++) {
        Planet planet = planetList.get(i);

        String name = planet.getName();
        double mass = planet.getMass();
        double distance = planet.getDistance();
        double period = planet.getPeriod();
        String habitable = planet.getHabitable();
        myString = myString + "Planet " + name + " has a mass of " + mass + " Earths, is " + distance
                + "AU from its star, and orbits in " + period + " years: could be habitable? " + habitable + "\n";
    }

    return myString;
}
}

class Planet {
SolarSystem system;
private final String name;
private final double mass;
private final double distance;
private double period;
private String habitable;
private final double luminosity;
private final double sqlum;

public Planet(String name, double mass, double distance, double luminosity) {
    this.name = name;
    this.mass = mass;
    this.distance = Math.round(distance * 1000.0) / 1000.0;
    this.luminosity = luminosity;
    this.period = Math.round(Math.sqrt(distance * distance * distance) * 1000.0) / 1000.0;
    this.sqlum = java.lang.Math.sqrt(luminosity);
    if ((mass >= 0.6) && (mass <= 7.0) && (distance >= (0.75 * sqlum)) && (distance <= (2.0 * sqlum))) {
        habitable = "yes";

    } else {
        habitable = "no";
    }
}

public SolarSystem getSystem() {
    return system;
}

public void setSystem(SolarSystem system) {
    this.system = system;
}

public double getPeriod() {
    return period;
}

public void setPeriod(double period) {
    this.period = period;
}

public String getHabitable() {
    return habitable;
}

public void setHabitable(String habitable) {
    this.habitable = habitable;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public double getMass() {
    return mass;
}

public double getDistance() {
    return distance;
}

public double getLuminosity() {
    return luminosity;
}

public double getSqlum() {
    return sqlum;
}

}
```